# Subversive: No update after commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Committed files are not updated to the newest revision ( still showing the same revision as before the commit). One need to update those files manually. Is this behavior intended, a config issues or just a bug?

Comment: svn won't update the files automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is the intended behavior. This lets other team members collaborating on the same project without messing each other files. Usually your team members should initiate manual update when they're ready.